# javascript: problem with function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    jQuery(function($){
        function here(b){alert(b);} ;
        here(6);
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

and i have this button on page:

```
<button onclick="here(7);">TEST</button>
```

The alert fires on page load, but not on button click. If i replace the here(7) with alert, it works fine. Why doesnt it work with function though?

Alan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your function is defined within a function, it has a limited scope.  To access the function globally, you must define it globally.  **But**, this is not recommended.  This is why you use libraries like jQuery, to avoid all the globals and to keep things unobtrusive.  The best solution for you would be to change the markup to this...

```
<button id="myBtn">TEST</button>
```

And then assign the click handler programmatically in the same area as your defined function...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[ 
    jQuery(function($) { 
        function here(b) { alert(b); };    
        here(6); 

        $("#myBtn").click(function() {
          here(7);
        });
    }); 
//]]> 
</script>
```

Behavioral separation is much better, wouldn't you say?

Comment: Not really. In this case my template would feed parameters to each function, if i do it unobtrusively, then i would have to do much more complex script, that reads those parameters from elements around button...

in any case. i understand, what you mean, so i'll do it in a different way.

Comment: *that reads those parameters from elements around button* What?  You don't need to do anything like that.  When you say "from my template" you mean they are values coming from the backend system (PHP or whatever)?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the function `here` inside another function (see [closures](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html)). This means that the function `here` is only available inside the scope of `jQuery(function($){`

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    function here(b){alert(b);} ;
    jQuery(function($){
        here(6);
    });
//]]>
</script>
```